# Removing cells from scene2d.ui tables

Tags: libgdx

I'm trying to remove a row from a table and have everything below that row move up one row. I am not succeeding at all. I've tried iterating through all the cells (with `Table.getCells()`) and updating them that way in various ways, but it just doesn't seem to work the way I intend to. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Did you try to update the table via Table.layout() or Table.invalidate() after removing the cell/row?

Comment: Yeah it didn't make a difference for what I was doing at the time, but I got it working now.

Comment: thanks, it works! But in my case, I've invoked the 'pack()' method instead of 'invalidate', to shrink the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some sleep solved the problem! The example below removes the first row from a table with 2 columns and moves all other rows up one step.

```
List<Cell> cells = table.getCells(); 

//Remove contents of first row
cells.get(0).setWidget(null);
cells.get(1).setWidget(null);

//Copy all cells up one row
for (int i = 0; i < cells.size() - 2; i++)
    cells.set(i, cells.get(i + 2));

//Remove the last row
cells.remove(cells.size() - 1);
cells.remove(cells.size() - 1);
```

Answer (score 6):

You can remove `Actor` with it cell like this:

```
public static void removeActor(Table container, Actor actor) {
    Cell cell = container.getCell(actor);
    actor.remove();
    // remove cell from table
    container.getCells().removeValue(cell, true);
    container.invalidate();
}
```

It's not very handsome solution but it works

Answer (score 2):

A cleaner solution would be the next:

```
public void removeTableRow(int row) {

     SnapshotArray<Actor> children = table.getChildren();
     children.ordered = false;

     for (int i = row*COLUMN_NUMBER; i < children.size - COLUMN_NUMBER; i++) {
         children.swap(i, i + COLUMN_NUMBER);
     }

     // Remove last row
     for(int i = 0 ; i < COLUMN_NUMBER; i++) {
         table.removeActor(children.get(children.size - 1));
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This works pretty well for me after trying all the earlier responses.

```
    deleteStockButton.addListener(new ChangeListener() {
        public void changed(ChangeListener.ChangeEvent event, Actor actor) {
            if (stockTableIndex != null) {
                try {
                    Table stockTable = (Table) stockScroll.getActor();
                    List<Actor> cells = new ArrayList<>();
                    for (Cell c : stockTable.getCells().toArray(Cell.class)) {
                        cells.add(c.getActor());
                    }
                    cells.remove(stockTableIndex);

                    stockTable.clearChildren();

                    for (Actor a : cells) {
                        stockTable.row().pad(2);
                        stockTable.add(a).height(TEXT_HEIGHT).left().expandX();
                    }

                    stockTable.layout();

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                stockTableIndex = null;
            }
        }
    });
```